# Remove period ONLY after doi and url in bibliography in model5-names.bst (elsarticle.cls)

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle, doi

The model5-names.bst style from elsarticle.cls adds period after DOIs in the bibliography. I would like to remove it when DOI is present, but retain it in its absence.

For example:

Kanizsa, G. (1976). Subjective contours. *Scientific American, 234*(4), 48–52.

and

Kanizsa, G. (1976). Subjective contours. *Scientific American, 234*(4), 48–52. doi:123456789

but not

Kanizsa, G. (1976). Subjective contours. *Scientific American, 234*(4), 48–52. doi:123456789.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that the style `model5-names` adds a period after *all* formatted entries, not just the ones that contain a `doi` field. To modify this behavior, you need to modify the function `fin.entry` in the bst file. Edit a *copy* of the bst file, *not* the original bst file.

Specifically, you should change the function from

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}
```

to

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ doi empty$
    { add.period$ }
    { }
  if$
  write$
  newline$
}
```

Doing so will add a test of whether the `doi` field is empty; the `add.period$` instruction is executed only if the test is true.

Comment: Thank you Mico for your altruism! You've saved me three times already :))).

Comment: Mico, one more problem... :-( APA style requires "Retrieved from URL" if DOI is absent for an online article. Is there a way to do this in the model5-names.bst? Sorry for nagging you...

Comment: @Gaijin - For a substantially new question, please post a new query. Separately, please consider upvoting (as well as accepting) answers you find helpful.

Comment: Got it! Will post it as a separate question. Thank you!