# Removing period after DOI using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

This question is very related to the following example.

[Remove period ONLY after doi and url in bibliography in model5-names.bst (elsarticle.cls)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270732/remove-period-only-after-doi-and-url-in-bibliography-in-model5-names-bst-elsart)

I would like to remove the period after the DOI, but not after the year, in case the bibliographic item is missing the DOI number, using biblatex.

For example (taken from the above link),

Kanizsa, G. (1976). Subjective contours. Scientific American, 234(4), 48–52.

and

Kanizsa, G. (1976). Subjective contours. Scientific American, 234(4), 48–52. doi:123456789

but not

Kanizsa, G. (1976). Subjective contours. Scientific American, 234(4), 48–52. doi:123456789.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = authortitle,
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
author = {Lily},
title = {Trees},
journaltitle = {Journal of Trees},
year = {2015},
}

@article{b,
author = {John},
title = {Flowers},
journaltitle = {Journal of Flowers},
year = {2015},
doi = {17.7-31893.23},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will think of a cleverer way, but in the meantime try

```
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:doi} and not test {\iffieldundef{doi}}}{}{\addperiod}}
```

Comment: Isn't the boolean `toggle`?

Comment: Isn't this clever enough? :)

Comment: This worked beautifully.

Comment: @Bernard Within an `\ifboolexpr` the keywords are `togl`, `bool` and `test`. So `togl` is the correct keyword for a toggle defined via `\newtoggle{bbx:doi}`.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for the information! I had not seen it inn the documentation – I must say I didn't look very long through it.