# biblatex-apa does not consistently remove period after DOI when using the option backref. How to fix this?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, back-referencing, apa7

It can be seen in the following MWE that, when `backref = true`, for reference types like `book`, (and in fact almost every other type than `article`, from my tests) `biblatex-apa` does not remove the period after DOI, which is against APA 7th standards.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend = biber,
  style = apa,
  backref = true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{a,
    author  = {Aron, A. A.},
    title   = {Example article},
    journal = {Example Journal},
    year    = {2022},
    doi     = {10.1000/example.a}
  }

  @book{b,
    author  = {Brown, B. B.},
    title   = {Example book},
    year    = {2022},
    doi     = {10.1000/example.b}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencite{a} \parencite{b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE showing biblatex-apa not removing the period after DOI for book entry]

On Stack Exchange, I only found one relevant discussion about a similar problem for `authortitle` style:

[Removing period after DOI using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382910/removing-period-after-doi-using-biblatex)

The solution provided there does not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Googling, I found that this issue has been resolved in an unreleased version of `biblatex-apa`:

https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/pull/159

Before this version becomes available to users, adding the following lines to the document preamble after `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` seems to solve the issue:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{https://doi.org/#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{https://doi.org/#1}}%
  \nopunct%
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}\nopunct}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \bibstring{retrieved}\space#1%
  \urldatecomma\bibstring{from}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{doi+url}{%
  \ifboolexpr{          test {\iffieldundef{doi}}
                 or not togl {bbx:doi}}
    {\ifboolexpr{       test {\iffieldundef{url}}
                 or not togl {bbx:url}}
       {\newunit}
       {\usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}
    {\printfield{doi}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{url}\OR\NOT\iffieldundef{doi}}
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{urlyear}
      {}
      {\bibstring{retrieved}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printurldate
       \setunit{\urldatecomma}%
       \bibstring{from}%
       \setunit{\addspace}}%
     \printfield{url}}%
}
```

These lines are obtained from the changes in the new version's `apa.bbx` file, except the `\newbibmacro*`s are replaced with `\renewbibmacro*`s.

[image]